# Learning C. After K&R

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [After K&R what book to use to learn programming in plain C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803522/after-kr-what-book-to-use-to-learn-programming-in-plain-c)

I have read K&R and gone through the exercises and am looking to continue learning. Can anyone give me advice on interesting books or resources to learn from? Are there any interesting C libraries I can learn to take my understanding of C past the intro provided by K&R, because I'm slightly at a loss.
I thought I might look at ARToolkit, just to mess around with it in conjuunction with OpenGL

Comment: Which field(s) are you interested in? Looks like graphics from you wanting to look into ARToolkit. Do you want to learn more about a specific domain or the language in general?

Comment: If you understand everything you read in K&R, you probably have enough knowledge to start *working* in C, writing actual useful programs. Rather than looking for another book to continue trying to learn, I would recommend trying to contribute to an open-source project or just getting your hands dirty writing an app that you *personally* would find useful. There comes a time when reading and study don't do as much good as actually working with the language.

Comment: K&R actually covers just about all of the important parts of the C language. You should probably read a book on programming in C for the specific platform (Linux, Win32 whatever) that you are interested in. Or better still, learn C++ :-)

Comment: Well I dont know specifically what area I want to concentrate on. I'm not so interested in graphics. Just ARToolkit looks fun. After reading K&R slowly and doing various exercises I dont feel likeI'm ready to do anything useful. I could probably easily knock up a console application doing something or other, but I always think to myself, why dont I just do this in Java? As a "systems language" its difficult to get in to it if I dont know that much about "systems". I'd love ot one day be able to write a driver for some hardware, but that day is a long way off.