# entering a char using scanf and saving it in an int can cause undefined behaviour?

Tags: c

I am working on a code, and I tried to enter a char instead of integer, and the result was '2' regardless of the character I entered, is it undefined behaviour or some thing else ?

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int f1(int n);
int f2(void);

int main(void)
{
    int t;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &t);
    /* print proper message */
    t ? f1(t) + f2() : printf("zero entered.\n");
    return 0;
}

int f1(int n)
{
    printf("%d ", n);
    return 0;
}

int f2(void)
{
    printf("entered.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

when I entered `a`, the result was "2 entered", and when I entered `g` the result was "2 entered" and when I entered `i,h,k,.....` the result was the same. What is that?

Comment: What's the point of the addition : `f1(t) + f2()` ?

Comment: @Michael concatenate the output on the screen...

Comment: @A4L Uh... that's not how it works.

Comment: Here, `f1(t)+f2()` should at least be replaced with `f1(t),f2()`. Even more clear would be an `if` statement: `if (t) { f1(t); f2(); } else { printf("zero entered.\n"); }`

Comment: @thejh it's `0 + 0` and the side effect are the two `printf`s in `f1` and `f2` witch then look like `"2 entered"` ... that's a weird way of writing a message anyways ...

Comment: @A4L, this will only add returned values (`0` in both functions) and not use the result... Anyway, use `scanf("%c", &t)` instead of `scanf("%d", &t)`

Comment: @A4L Yes, I understand that. However, I think that `+` should be avoided here because you're not using the result, and so it just makes the code unclear.

Comment: This code does not have any rhyme or reason.

Comment: I am totally agreed with @thejh

Comment: @Michael I agree too, `+` is just misleading makes no sense in this case.

Comment: this code explains that The use of the ? operator to replace if-else statements is not restricted to assignments
only. this code is from c++ the complete reference by Herbert Schildt

Comment: @ArmiaWagdy: In all seriousness, you should [absolutely avoid any books by Schildt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803522/after-kr-what-book-to-use-to-learn-programming-in-plain-c/803554#803554)...

Comment: @ArmiaWagdy - Do you have a shredder - it needs feeding - why not give it that book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `scanf` failed to parse you input. It expects you to enter a [**decimal digits**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/) since you used `%d`.

You have to check the return value of `scanf` to avoid this kind of behavior :

> On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading error, or the reach of the end-of-file.

So :

```
int items_matched;

// ...
items_matched = scanf("%d", &t);   // Get the return value

if ( items_matched != 1 )          // Check it
{
    printf("Matching failure with scanf.\n");
    return 0;
}
else
{
    if ( t == 0 )
        printf("zero entered\n");
    else
        printf("%d entered\n", t);
}
```

You don't need your `f1(t) + f2()` who is quite confusing...

Comment: Did you mean that if the code was :#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){

int t,m;
int items_matched;

// ...
printf("Enter two numbers : ");
items_matched = scanf("%d,%d", &t,&m);   // Get the return value

if ( items_matched != 2 )          // Check it
{
    printf("Matching failure with scanf.\n");
    return 0;
}
else
{
    if ( t == 0 )
        printf("zero entered\n");
    else
        printf("%d entered\n", t);
}
}

Comment: actually An Int and Char can be interexchanged.. 'A' == 65

Comment: @JoeDF Yes that is true. I edited my answer for something better. Thanks for pointing this out !

Answer (score 3):

If `scanf()` encounters something it cannot parse based on the specified format string, it simply stops and returns early.  So it never writes anything to `t` (you're just seeing whatever indeterminate value `t` had before the call).

To handle this, you should always examine the *return* value of `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, as you say, that scanf using %d format is expecting you to enter one or more ascii digits.  It stops scanning the input at a non-digit character, so it never reads what you type and t has whatever value it had before the scant was called.

Comment: actually An Int and Char can be interexchanged.. 'A' == 65

Comment: True, but irrelevant to the parsing behaviour of scant.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the return code of `scanf`. Have a look at [the manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf):

> Return Value
>
> These functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.
>
> The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs. EOF is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set indicate the error.

In other words, `scanf` does not write anything into `t`, it's uninitialized the whole time.

So, instead of this:

```
scanf("%d", &t);
```

try this:

```
int items_matched = scanf("%d", &t);
if (items_matched != 1) {
    printf("bad number entered\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf)

> The format string consists of a sequence of directives which describe
>   how to process the sequence of input characters. If processing of a
>   directive fails, **no further input is read**, and scanf() returns. A
>   "failure" can be either of the following: input failure, meaning that
>   input characters were unavailable, or matching failure, meaning that
>   the input was inappropriate.

In the C11 standard description of scanf (**7.21.6.4 The scanf function**) section 3:

> The scanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input
>   failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed.
>   Otherwise, the scanf function returns the number of input items
>   assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, **or even zero, in the
>   event of an early matching failure**.

Emphasis is mine . So as @oli charlesworth said you should check the return value of scanf when in doubt :)