# What will happen if scanf() gets some character which doesn't match the format string?

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, k;
    scanf("%d%d%d", &i, &j, &k);
    printf("%d %d %d", i, j, k);
    return 0;
}
```

If we input `1,2,3`, what will happen? And why?

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/18297691/2646069 , if `scanf()` reads an unexpected string, it will return early thus not modifying any value after the last successful value.

I tried clang (LLVM 6.1.0), on `-O0`, the explanation above is correct, but on `-O2`, the second variable is always a random number but not the same as before `scanf()`, and the third variable is always `0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fscanf.html), `scanf`s return value tells you whether it's safe to use those arguments or not.

> Upon successful completion, these functions shall return the number of successfully matched and assigned input items; this number can be zero in the event of an early matching failure. If the input ends before the first matching failure or conversion, EOF shall be returned. If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set, EOF shall be returned

If you were to input `1,2,3` then `scanf` would return `1`, indicating that the first argument is safe to use and that a match failure occured at the first `,` because it doesn't match the input expected according to the format string.

If you were to make use of `j` or `k` following this, then your code would be making use of an indeterminite value, which is undefined behaviour, obviously a source of erratic behaviour to be avoided... It's very important that you **check the return value of `scanf`**, as the link you used also encourages.

Answer (score 1):

The [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18297683/2455888) given there is correct. `scanf` will stop and return when it will find `,` in input. Therefore `j` and `k` will be uninitialized. Uninitialized variables have indeterminate values and this will invoke undefined behavior if it is a trap representation.

Comment: `j` and `k` would be indeterminite. Uninitialised variables don't invoke undefined behaviour, though they are indeterminite. Using indeterminite values invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour; Yes. Ultimately they will invoke UB.