# Good follow-up to Kernighan and Ritchie's "C Programming Language" 2nd Edition

Tags: c

Just finished self-studying C with "The C Programming Language, 2nd Ed." by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie, and am looking for a good follow-up book that can kind of pick up where that book left of - specifically pertaining to programming C under Linux (sockets, threading, IPC, etc.).  I did the search thing, but there are so many books (some of them quite expensive) that it is hard to pick one.

I know the Kernighan/Ritchie book is frequently used in C programming courses, so I was kind of curious what schools (and other self-learners) have been using after it?

Comment: Primarily opinion based and also a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803522/after-kr-what-book-to-use-to-learn-programming-in-plain-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read [Deep C secrets](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131774298) as a follow-up. But I also strongly recommend you to read [comp.lang.c Frequently Asked Questions](http://www.c-faq.com/). As K&R is very old , so you also need to brush up your self with C's new standards, C99/ C11.

For network programming you can follow [Unix Network Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551).

Comment: Great! Thanks for the suggestions.  I recognize that K&R is kind of old, but it worked great for my purposes. Much deeper examples then I have had in learning other languages - IMO really basic examples don't do much to get one thinking.  And, I zipped through it in about a week.  I will look into Deep C Secrets.